# A subspace $Y$ of a topological space $X$ is discrete iff $\exists$ open cover of $X$ in which every open subset contatins exactly one element of $Y$

Tags: general-topology

I have proved the one side. Suppose that there is an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of $X$ such that $|U_{\alpha}\cap Y|=1$ for all $\alpha\in I$.
Let $y\in Y\subset X$, so there is $\alpha_y\in I$ such that $y\in U_{\alpha_y}$.
Since $|U_{\alpha_y}\cap Y|=1$, we have $\{y\}=U_{\alpha_y}\cap Y$, this implies $\{y\}$ is open in $Y$. Hence, any subset of $Y$ is open in $Y$.
$\therefore Y$ is discrete.
But I can't argue the converse part i.e. if subspace topology of $Y$ is discrete then there is an open cover of $X$ in which every open subset contains exactly one element from $Y$.
I am not sure about the construction of open cover. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The converse need not hold.

A Counter-Example:

Let $X = \{ a, b, c \}$, $Y = \{ a, b \}$, and let
$$
\mathscr{T}_X = \big\{ \emptyset, \{ a \}, \{ b \}, \{ a, b \}, X \big\}.
$$
Then the subspace topology on $Y$ is clearly the discrete topology. However, we cannot construct an open cover of $X$ in which every set intersects $Y$ in exactly one point.

As a general pattern, let $Y$ be any discrete space, and let $X$ be the set obtained by adjoining an extra element to set $Y$, that is, if $p$ is that element, then
$$
X = Y \cup \{ p \},
$$
and of course $p \not\in Y$.

Now let the topology of $X$ be given by
$$
\mathscr{T}_X = \mathscr{P}(Y) \bigcup \{ X \}.
$$

Comment: another example would be a (non-trivial) converging sequence together with the limit point. Consider that as a topological space, and removing the limit point we get a discrete subspace, but for every open cover and an open set from the cover that contains the limit point, it must also contain infinitely many of the other points.

Comment: Is this statement true if $X$ is topological group? I'm asking because of the definition of discrete subgroup in wikipedia 
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_group#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20discrete%20subgroup,G%20is%20the%20discrete%20topology.